# Calculating polynomials in a Galois field

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

I'm in $\text{GF}(8) = \text{GF}(2^3)$ and have an irreducbile polynomial $p(x) = x^3 + x + 1$, then $\text{GF}(8) = \mathbb{Z}_2[x]/\langle p(x) \rangle$ .

Now I want to multiply $2$ elements of the field, namely $(x^2 + x + 1)\cdot (x^2 + x + 1)$. I get the result $x + 2$ with the remainder $2x^2 - x - 1$ if I multiply these two elements and then divide the resulting polynomial by the polynomial $p(x)$.

The result of the multiplication should be $x + 1$, but how do I get from $2x^2 - x - 1$ to $x + 1$?

Comment: The field has characteristic $2$. Note that $1 = -1$

Comment: But where goes the 2x^2??

Comment: Characteristic $2$ means $2 = 0$, i.e. multiplying any element (such as $x^2$) by $2$, gives $0$

Comment: $2x^2$ is coming from $x^2+x^2$. WE ARE OVER $\Bbb Z_2$ where $1+1=0$. So, $x^2+x^2=x^2(1+1)=0$. 
To put it in other words: *'the base field* where the coefficients are coming from *does not contain the number **two**'*.

Comment: Berci's (+1) answer describes the idea, and works out this example in detail. For more applications of the same ideas you may want to study this [CW-question/answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/591254/11619).

Answer (score 1):

Think this way:

> To arrive at $GF_8$ we extended the base field $\Bbb Z_2$ by a *root* (say $\alpha$) of $p(x)=x^3+x+1$.

Observe that $\alpha\in GF_8$ would play the role of $x$, as $x^3+x+1=0$ in the quotient $\Bbb Z_2[x]/(p(x))$ just as $\alpha^3+\alpha+1=0$ (because $\alpha$ is a root 'somewhere out in the world' of $p(x)$).

So the suggestion is to simply write $\alpha$ for $x$ and use the only equation that we know:
$$\alpha^3+\alpha+1=0$$
Since we are over $\Bbb Z_2$, this is equivalent to $\alpha^3=\alpha+1$, and observe that $(A+B)^2=A^2+AB+AB+B^2=A^2+B^2$ here, because $X+X=0$ in any vector space over $\Bbb Z_2$ for any element $X$ (and a field containing $\Bbb Z_2$ is obviously a vector field over it).

Multiplying by $\alpha$, we also have $\alpha^4=\alpha^2+\alpha$, and so
$$(\alpha^2+\alpha+1)^2=\alpha^4+\alpha^2+1=\alpha^2+\alpha\,+\, \alpha^2\,+\,1=\alpha+1$$